# Can hate to same gender parent cause homosexualism?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, sexuality, gender

I know a girl who is (or claims to be) lesbian.
I also know that big part of her childhood (12-now years) she hated her mother.
Her father left family when she was infant (1-2 years). I dont know what she thinks about her father.
She is 17 now.

I wonder, is it possible that by not-accepting her mother, she does not accept her own gender? Or is it more likely that not having a father, influenced her sexual orientation?
Was any documented research conducted, that would confirm/reject that?
Any other thoughts on that?

### EDIT

I should have mention about it earlier but somehow I forgot about that.
I know that she had experiance when she got home earlier one day, and saw her mother with her lover having sex. She told it my sister. More or less after that, she started to dress like a man and (I think) she lost this 'little girl/child' identity. She become more serious and her marks at school rised very high. She is the best in class now but before that experience she was one of the worst.

I dont know if this is relevant, but she consider herself as a loner and watches a lot of anime now. I think this is all what I know about her.

I feel confused. I always thought that only small percent of people are really homosexual (because of chromosome mutation), and the rest just believes (because many possible reasons) that they are.

Comment: Almost every teenager hates their mother or father. Most people are mostly straight. How probable do you personally consider your hypothesis?

Comment: @jona; I think I can agree with that. About my hypothesis... I need to edit my question.

Comment: @DannyX I think you may be looking for a socialised or psychobabble explanation. I'll try to keep this less complex than my answer. Roughly 3% of any population is gay, its not a many but you are bound to meet people who are. Some teenagers may be gay, but as with all teenagers they are learning about themselves and their sexuality, when a person works out who they are they may become more confident. Confidence in yourself and being serious can improve performance. Although there are many motives for that too. Also being alone isn't so bad if your an introverts like at least 25-50% of people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gender is not, despite what others might say, [a social construct](http://www.annualreviews.org/doi/pdf/10.1146/annurev-neuro-061010-113654), and neither is [sexuality](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Paul_Wolpe/publication/8261924_Ethics_and_social_policy_in_research_on_the_neuroscience_of_human_sexuality/links/543336980cf20c6211be43ee.pdf), just google [David Rimmer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Reimer) to see what happens when researchers have messed with these. While we don't understand what causes homo-sexuality fully, typically speaking sexuality seems to be influenced by hormone exposure in the womb, when a [human is a foetus](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3138231/). Although studies have found that roughly 5-10% of people have had [same-sex sexual experiences](http://www.samesexattraction.org/how-many-are-gay.htm), this appears to be [relatively common in adolescence](http://ovidsp.tx.ovid.com/sp-3.18.0b/ovidweb.cgi?QS2=434f4e1a73d37e8c6d5cc3ea7a7100e0bdbc72cb40c7d35fa1a1823ee7be1e9292b151482656e17feec4a6ff213a471d4a3193ec569e96732de909045623f1da3b77521ac27e0496ac1264fc3678e073e97ea66cb4eebb91510e93560fd84a8fcc8cf073ce0169a8dfb7a577f15ddd29872dc6ff98945c4c1126564abe9ca2fc5dc97a1708bca1c0776bbc29ad3cbebc3dd58efacf2c0988e82bca35747c07c28c3942f004be9b2c20149e20b494eca1018862cc058ccd750e4fb7d0c14c553487b722f661d16564bb3889939a057f059688d3ff7ad5b411784fc951c7de7259) although it does happen later in life too. Speculatively its possible that this partly comes from people learning about themselves and their sexuality. However despite people having these same-sex experiences only [1-3% of people identify as homo or bisexual](http://www.ons.gov.uk/ons/rel/integrated-household-survey/integrated-household-survey/january-to-december-2012/info-sexual-identity.html). Why do people have these experiences? There are a a multitude of reasons, some people are homosexual, while some may be curious or undecided, or perhaps some other reason.

Ignoring the sexuality side and looking at group identification: people have all sorts of reasons for [identifying with particular groups](https://books.google.co.uk/books?hl=en&lr=&id=8Jzkgbq2vYwC&oi=fnd&pg=PA111&dq=social%20identification%20theory%20review&ots=425Z7KJpn5&sig=0iJ6H3mr479fa0B1BT7aBfTeNak#v=onepage&q=social%20identification%20theory%20review&f=false) or demographics. While relationships with parents are certainly cause for being rebelliousness, its not going to turn anyone homosexual who isn't already inclined. There seems to be **no recent evidence** about parenting style and sexuality, apart from on religious websites that have no place here, although [stonewall say that there is no relationship](https://www.stonewall.org.uk/sites/default/files/so_you_think_your_child_is_gay.pdf). However the research linking the two is absent, which usually suggests either it hasn't been researcher properly or, more likely, that there is no relationship at all.

Comment: -1. Can you provide *scientific* sources for all of your claims?

Comment: @jona First of all down voting me for missing a reference is a little petty. Most of my statements are scientifically backed, if possible, sure one is a summary of research but its based on well established research so it doesn't have to be a journal article itself, this is not a thesis. The other statements are supported by national statistics, or surveys carried out by groups that investigate homosexuality. There is nothing wrong with reporting these statistics, also some of my other references provide additional support if you had bothered to read them.

Comment: You provide a one-sided perspective on a controversial issue, and you do not provide proper scientific sources for your claims. Instead, you provide non-scientific ones (e.g. the "ideafarm" link), which is, by some measures, actually worse than providing none.

Comment: Its hardly controversial in terms of biology. While it may seem complicated the research is pretty unanimous, as you will see if you read the first and second reference. I have changed the reference, the support is no different for the statement, just more difficult to read for the person asking, clearly non-academic which is why I didn't use scientific papers first. As I mentioned some is speculation based upon survey statistics, I have stated "no evidence" where I could find none. Just because you disagree with a perspective doesn't make it wrong, in fact you are free to write an answer.

Comment: I still think this is a one-sided answer, but my criticism no longer applies.

Comment: I admit its very biological, but as I come from a neurocognitive perspective its all relatively clear cut. Of course the psychosocial approaches are far more complicated, but I wouldn't know where to start with that. Although it would be enlightening to have that here as well.

Comment: If gender is the association of "masculine" and "feminine" with expressions of identity then it can be argued that gender is a social construct. An individual's *gender identity*, on the other hand, can be argued as coming from the interplay of an individual's neurobiology with the social construct of gender. In the Rimmer case, his neurobiological gender identity appears to have been  *gender binary* (ie. "usual"), and his sexual orientation was heterosexual, but he had a gender identity and physiology imposed on him that left him suicidal.